# Grpc netty handler libraries are conflicting with OpenJSSE

Tags: netty, grpc-java, boringssl, skywalking

I'm facing a `classCastException` issue while using grpc netty handlers along with OpenJSSE.

We are working on gRPC calls (which use Netty handlers for SSL communication). However, this is a Java agent and is supposed to be on a different runtime. The runtime that we are trying to intercept is running on OpenJSSE using `-XX:+UseOpenJSSE`.

Here is the issue—running the gRPC client and server throws:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslEngine cannot be cast to org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine
```

Comment: Which gRPC version are you using?

Comment: I have tried many combinations of grpc and netty along with tcnative to find out a solution. Last tried with below versions

compile 'io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.35.0'
compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.35.0'
compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.35.0'
runtime 'io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:2.0.25.Final'
compile 'io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.52.Final'
compile 'io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:4.1.52.Final'

Comment: For people also being interested, the conversation continued on https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/7907.